# webscraping tables not returning any data

Tags: python, web-scraping

Required table's tr elements are seen in developer tools but not in source code for webscraping, for one particular url, tried selenium and everything else too, but no avail, what ever I try, all I'm getting as output is [], if anyone can help me sort it out, it would be of great help. 
First I tried with `beautifulsoup`, then `proxycrawl`, then few other ways but I'm not able to scrape it, it has download option, but I need this to be scraped to store in aws, automating it to get data daily scheduled at 6pm to stream on `powerbi` as soon as it gets updated.
url is `http://scheduling.nrldc.in/wbes/Report/PXIndex#date=16-04-2019|revisionno=null|type=5`

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the `WebDriverWait` to wait for the table to be rendered, but I was having issues with it, so rather just went with the `time.sleep`

But you can easily get that entire table by having Selenium click on the download csv button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = 'http://scheduling.nrldc.in/wbes/Report/PXIndex#date=16-04-2019|revisionno=null|type=5'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("dwnld").click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("CsvExport").click()
```

Comment: thank u for the quick response but how can i push this into rds mysql db instance in aws?